# Will "Out of stack space" error be trapped by error handler?

Tags: vb6, stack-overflow, runtime-error

Will an `"Out of stack space"` error be trapped by the VB6 error handler, or will it always result in a run-time error?

Comment: It will be trapped by caller function error handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be trapped by the error handler.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
  Count2 0
End Sub

Private Sub Count2(ByVal Value As Long)
  On Error GoTo x
  Count2 Value + 1
  Exit Sub
x:
  MsgBox "stack depth " & Value
  Err.Clear
End Sub
```

`stack depth 3659`

Comment: Regarding "question was either-or", Both are correct, it will result in a run time error that will be caught by the normal error handling. The unhandled runtime error **message** only appears when a runtime error is unhandled.

Comment: With respect, I think it's quite clear that the term 'run-time error' in my question refers to errors that have not been trapped. In any case, I don't think the question as put can logically be answered with a Yes/No.